# Export raster layer CreateDatasourceError

Tags: raster, pyqgis, export, error

In the first place, say that I'm new to this.

I'm trying to export with QGIS in Python some raster layers, following examples seen in this forum. Following the code:

```
layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    file_name = 'C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/' + layer.name() + '_.tif'
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(file_name)
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
   
    if not pipe.set(provider.clone()):
        print ("Cannot set pipe provider")
        continue

    r = file_writer.writeRaster(
        pipe,
        provider.xSize(),
        provider.ySize(),
        provider.extent(),
        provider.crs())
    print(r)
```

but the function `writeRaster` returns error 3. As I see in the documentation, this means `CreateDatasourceError`.

For more information, raster layer is selected on the left panel.
[image]

And this layer has been loaded from a .ecw file.

Any idea of where this error is coming from?

Comment: Can you share your data? I run the script with ecw file, no problem.

Comment: Sure, what data do you need? script? layers?

Comment: There may be the same-named file and windows may not allow overwriting.

Comment: There is no other file with the same name in the target folder. How can I share ECW file? is too large, over 2GB

Comment: I have created a repository with an example of code with a tif layer. In this case I get the same error with tif and ecw layer when I try to export. The QGIS version is 3.22 but also a tested with 3.16 with same result.

This is the link to repository in gitlab:
https://gitlab.com/aparra4169/qgis_test_save/

Comment: It works your script without error.